# How to lock a table in ms access using .net

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access

So I have been looking for a while but I have not found what I exactly need:

I have an old application that uses some 2001 ms access database (MDB), However I recently require that a certain table to be password-locked for editing. Unfortunately I have no way to access or modify the old program so I am forced to try to "lock" that table externally.

The ideal solution would have the table be locked/unlocked by entering a password in an external program (.net for example). I have yet to find a suitable method to lock the table. Some solutions I looked at were:

1- Splitting the database, but it wouldn't work without changing the source code of the program and I am not sure it would work in the end.

2- Keeping a copy of the records of the "locked" table and re-writing it if there are any changes

This however feel very "hack-y" so I would like to see if I can lock this database for a more clean solution

I know such a feature exists in MS access 2013 but I am not sure if it exists for the previous versions.

Comment: You can lock the database file (and opening it from .Net usually does that), but not the single table.

Comment: Yea, That does happen to be the problem I am facing, I am also considering whatever other options I have but I am not sure of what solutions could exist for this issue.

Comment: There is no such option, as far as I know, indeed not when you can't modify the old program.

Comment: I see.. I will keep the question open for a while for the possibility that someone might know, But I will perhaps proceed to somehow "lock" the system when they try to edit that table. Thanks for letting me know though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there not really a built in feature that allows you to lock and un-lock a table. However, there is work group security, or so called User Level Security (ULS).

So you would not “lock” the table, but give users “write/update” rights to the given table. So with an mdb file format, ULS is certainly an option that would allow you to control what kind of rights to given objects (tables/forms/reports etc.).

You could thus by automation add or remove the default admin logon from say a security group that gives “write” privileges to the users of the database. Note that I say “default” Admin logon, since if you use any other user name to start a Access database, then users will be prompted for a logon + password when Access starts.

However as noted, this would assume you setup ULS on that database. (i.e.: add workgroup security to the database).

If you don’t want the hassle of setting up ULS, then next question is the Access UI locked down?

Often, an application will lock out the UI, and thus users can’t use the built in Access UI, but ONLY forms/reports/menus to interact with the data. If the UI is locked down, then you could simply set the form(s) that edit the datable to read only.

This approach is not “huge” secure as users would be able to import data into another database, but it might suffice to prevent users from accidently editing data. If the users have good access skills they certainly would be able to get around this approach. However hiding and preventing users from say opening tables directly and ONLY allowing them to use the forms etc. provided by the developer would allow “easy” toggle of the forms the users work with.

Again, this suggestion depends on how locked down the application UI now is, and how well the developer(s) made efforts to prevent use of the access built in features.

ULS or so called workgroup security does not require the UI change, but you have to test/try ULS on a copy as it is a complicated subject. However, ULS would thus allow the kind of security rights being applied to a given table and this includes read ability, write ability or even no rights to the given object such as tables.

Comment: While unfortunately inapplicable to my application this had gave me a good starting point. I will look at the ULS and see if I can somehow make use of it

Comment: Just keep in mind that ULS is only supported for mdb formats - it been depreciated for accDB file formats.